# Creating a hyperlink in an email template

Tags: email-template

For some reason, I can't get that to appear as a clickable link on my HTML email template.

Here is the exact code I'm putting into the HTML template :

```
<a href="https://fastfor.ms/ZS42BA?Survey__c.Client__c={!Incident__c.IncIDText__c}">LINK TEXT</a>
```

And for some reason that is not appearing as a hyperlink on the template.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please follow this step, it will work.

1. Create a HTML Email Template.
2. Write "Link" word, in the body.
3. Highlight the "Link" word and then click on hyperlink icon on the Formatting Controls toolbar.
4. Specify the path only.

[image: Html Email template]

Comment: This is not environment/sandbox free. To avoid post deployment step of editing the URLs in email templates we can use a formula field - `LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_360, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_360))`